Strapi API and filter request
I have a Strapi project, and when I try to get an entry with a specific value, it gives me all the results.
When I try to put this request :
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/people?filters[lastName][$eq]=Doe" \  -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"

the CLI gives me this :
curl: (3) bad range in URL position 42:
http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/people?filters[lastName][]=Doe
                                         ^

So I execute this command (replace "[" and "]" by  "%5B" and "%5D") :
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/people?filters%5BlastName%5D%5Beq%5D=Doe" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"

But it gives me all the entries.
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "attributes": {
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "createdAt": "2024-05-15T20:50:42.148Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T20:50:42.148Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-05-15T20:50:42.142Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "attributes": {
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "createdAt": "2024-05-15T21:07:30.250Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T21:07:32.543Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-05-15T21:07:32.541Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 2
    }
  }
}

And this is the expecting result :
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "attributes": {
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "createdAt": "2024-05-15T20:50:42.148Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T20:50:42.148Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-05-15T20:50:42.142Z"
      }
    },
    
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 1
    }
  }
}

I tried to search, but I didn't find many results with the same problem as mine.

Try like this
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/people?filters%5BlastName%5D%5B%24eq%5D=Doe" -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"

